# Improper Integrals: if one term diverges then...

Tags: improper-integrals

I would like to know if it is true that if one term (summand) diverges then the whole improper integral diverges. I would have thought that it would be like splitting a fraction, that divergance of the numerator *can/may* be compensated by the denominator, so it tells you nothing, that i would have to check if the other is finite.

If i split an improper integral:

$$\int_a^b fdx = \int_a^b g+h dx = \int_a^b g dx + \int_a^bh dx$$

then the Prof. says that if i can show that $\int_a^b gdx$ diverges then i dont even have to check the other summand.

(I realize that the statement would be true if we were considering absolute values but the Prof. did not mention absolute value/convergence)

Comment: Let $\int_a^b f\,dx$ converge, and $\int_a^b b\,dx$ diverge. Then what about $g = (f - b)$, $h = b$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Let $\int b$ also diverge but to the opposite infinity, does +inf-inf not have a chance to converge?

Comment: Well, that's my point, the badnesses can cancel. They do in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true under extra conditions. For instance that the summands
are non-negative. If it would be true without conditions then every
integral would diverge.

Let it be that $\int fdx$ diverges. Then $\int gdx=\int\left(g-f\right)+fdx$
would diverge too.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Thanks.